manifest error: MainActivity must extend android.app.Activity
In my manifest I have a red line under the activites name that says
MainActivity must extend android.app.Activity

but I can run the application normally on my physical mobile but when I try to Intent from one activity to another
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);startActivity(intent);

I got an error on startActivity that says
Cannot resolve method 'startActivity' in 'MainActivity'

and a red lined under
MainActivity.this, SignIn.class

I searched on stackoverflow to put
view.getContext

or other solutions but it didn't work for me. I used chatgpt but it only says to double check my package and imports and rebuild, clean and cache my project but with no solution And I'm sure that every thing in Manifest and gradle is correct
And android studio suggest for me to use
suppress: Add tools:ignore="instantiatable" attribute

EDIT: NOTE that when i make my activites extend Activity only it works but i wanna now why this happen and how to fix it because i want to extend AppCompatActivity like normal.... I think that AppCompatActivity doesn't extend Activity, but any help will be appreciated
here is my manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.tbgroup">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TBGroup"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn" // here is the error under the activity name
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" // here is the error under the activity name
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

and here are my activities
package com.example.tbgroup;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}

package com.example.tbgroup;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);


}
}


I suggest that you edit your question to provide the source code to MainActivity and SignIn.

okay but i think it does't matter

"I think that AppCompatActivity doesn't extend Activity" -- yes, it does (indirectly, by means of ComponentActivity). Your code seems fine, but your IDE seems to be confused. If you are using Android Studio, first try Build > Clean Project from the main menu, followed by Build > Rebuild Project from the main menu. If that does not clear up the problem, try File > Invalidate Caches from the main menu.

still it doesn't work for me.... can't I make appcompatActivity extend activity manually

You can't just reference any class, but it MUST extend Activity or a sub-class thereof.
For example, the most common declarations would be:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {}


but why is this i mean what is the reason for this.... actually the error disappear when i extend Activity ..... but i want to now the reason for this and fix it cause i wanna extend appcompat activity

It does not matter the least what you want, when the framework dictates it; you have no other choice. In best case, you could let MainActivity extend some custom eg. BaseActivity, which extends any of these Activity classes, but there are definitely no further options available. One has to work with the framework, not against the framework - trying to reinvent the wheel leads nowhere.
